# Get SD card serial / oemid from U-boot on RaspberryPi3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bootloader, u-boot, sysfs

I'm using U-boot on raspberry pi 3 and I want to obtain SD card `oemid` or `serial` number.

"Normally" it can be done by accessing `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/` or by running `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdX` on linux site, but I wonder:

Is that possible via U-Boot (i.e. without running kernel) ?

Comment: You should probably ask this on [raspberry pi stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think this concerns U-Boot so I'll leave it here for a couple of days and then remove if no answer (and I will also ask there, thanks for hint)

Comment: What is your final goal for this information?  For example, 'mmcinfo' gives some of what you need, but cannot be shoved into a script.  On the other hand, if you're trying to pass in root=PARTUUID= that information can be found in a scriptable way.

Comment: @TomRini : that's exactly what I want to do. Can you share some info?

Answer (score 2):

So, in order to get enough information from a device to be able to use the *root=PARTUUID=* syntax with the Linux kernel you need to have a few commands enabled in U-Boot.  A functional example of this can be found [here](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=include/configs/ti_armv7_common.h;h=ba7cf15242f6422011b05ac4045d949269ea033b;hb=HEAD#l59).  The shell prompt command is just:

```
=> part uuid INTERFACE DEVICE:PARTITION variable-to-store-in
```

And this requires that you have CONFIG_CMD_PART set which in turn requires CONFIG_PARTITION_UUIDS.